# Printer's paper sizes and my image

Tags: c#, image

My printer could handle only B3 and A4 sizes, I am working on an application to concatenate images. These images are of different sizes. I would like to know how to neatly arrange all of them into one single image file before printing it in A4 or B3.

For concatenation, I have got the working code but still am stuck at how the images should be arranged to fit the output paper size above.  Thank you for any ideas

```
public Image DrawLstOfItem(List<string> imgPath)
{
    string path = imgPath.First();
    Image img = Image.FromFile(path);
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, (int)(img.Height*imgPath.Count+(5.0f*(imgPath.Count-1))));
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);
        float nY = img.Height + 5.0f;
        float nX = 0.0f;
        for (int i = 1; i < imgPath.Count; i++)
        {
            Image nextImg = Image.FromFile(imgPath[i]);
            g.DrawImage(nextImg, nX, nY, nextImg.Width, nextImg.Height);
            nY += nextImg.Height + 0.5f;
        }
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

I need to detect input image sizes, calculate the possible outcomes and arrange them when the requirement is B3 or A4 respectively. I am messed up with all different ideas and really need someone to enlighten me so I can find a likely optimal path to move on.

Comment: Can you show an example of what you have just now, and where you are stuck?

Comment: Sure, why not ? I updated my post ;)

Comment: Have you looked into PrintDocument class? There is stuff in that class that can help you.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you would like to take a handful of images of various sizes and run them through some algorithm that would turn them into a "collage" that is a single image and that the bounds of that single image would be based on the paper-size selected?